# Android - Room - Initializing in App

Tags: android, android-room

I'm switching over to Room for my database logic, but I'm having a hard time finding the best solution for handling initialization.

Previously, my app launches into `MainActivity`, checks if the database is null, and if it is, opens `SplashActivity` to show a loading screen while it setups the database.

With Room, I'm trying to do something similar, or possibly just removing the `SplashActivity` and having empty views for the contents while it's loading. Although I would need to be able to tell if it's loading, or just has no contents.

Here is my current attempt at a solution, I have a flag `initialized` that defaults to `true`, if the callback hits `onCreate`, I set it to `false` and init the database. Once it has been setup, I set it `true`, and fire an event to notify the `SplashActivity`.

```
abstract class MyRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    fun init() {
        val gson = App.application.gson

        val content = gson.fromJsonFile(MY_FILE, Content::class.java)

        content.let {
            contentDao().insertAll(it.values)
        }

        // load the other content
    }

    companion object {

        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: MyRoomDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): MyRoomDatabase =
                INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                    INSTANCE ?: buildDatabase(context).also { INSTANCE = it }
                }


        fun buildDatabase(context: Context): MyRoomDatabase {
            val database = Room.databaseBuilder(context, MyRoomDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME)
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .addCallback(object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
                        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                            super.onCreate(db)
                            Logger.d("Database onCreate!")
                            getInstance(context).initialized = false

                            Single.fromCallable {
                                getInstance(context).init()

                                Logger.e("Database now initialized -- firing event.")

                                getInstance(context).initialized = true
                                App.application.postBusEvent(SetupDatabaseEvent())
                            }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                    .subscribe()
                        }

                        override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                            super.onOpen(db)
                            Logger.e("Database already initialized.")
                        }
                    }).build()

            INSTANCE = database

            return database

        }
    }
}
```

There are a lot of issues with this solution, such as the storage usage seems to sometimes spike. After init it could be 500KB, then restarting the app may make it jump to 6MB. Other than that, I also don't think it's very safe.

What would be a better way to initialize this database? I want to know when it's ready, and when I should block the user.

I also need an `Object` from my database right away to setup my `MainActivity`'s view. A user can select an `Object`, I mark that as `isSelected`, and next time they enter the app, I want to be able to show that `Object` as the current selection.

With Room, I need to fetch the current `Object` in the background, which makes it harder for me to display it correctly right away.

Other than caching in `SharedPreferences`, I'd like to know a way to pre-fetch this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreicated, thanks!

Comment: I think you can simplify your code by showing the splash screen or loading progress only when onCreate() fires, so for the first time DB is created. In other cases - show the activity right away. And if you need to load some data, just show the progress inside the task/thread, and not put this logic into RoomDb class.